# How to use jquery ajax to fill a div without affecting other contents in the same html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, overlay

I am building a live search field with jquery/ajax/php/html:

```
  $("#keywords").keyup(function()
  {
    var word = $("#keywords").val();
    if(word != '')  
     {
      $.ajax
       ({
         type: "POST",
     url: "mysearch.php",
     data: "word="+ word,
     success: function(response)
     {
        $("#results").html(response);
     }.....
```

And I have an empty div stub in the html page:

```
    <div id="results"></div>;
```

I was able to implement mysearch.php and get the results back and fill the "results" div with the response. However, when the response fills into the "results" div, other lines of contents in the same html page moves down in order to give space to the "results" div. I really don't like this because it feels that the screen is shaking.

Is there any way for me to modify this so that when the response comes back to fill the "results" div, it shows up in a new layer and my contents in the existing layer stays there? If there are some overlapping contents I would like the new response "results" div to overwrite the existing layer (and existing layer content change to hidden).

thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the HTML as well, please?

Comment: what if content of new layer is smaller than old layer??
should old layer still exist or remaining portion of older layer which is not covered by smaller layer should be shown

Comment: absolute position of the results div would prevent other content being displaced

Comment: Josh -sorry but the whole html is too big to post in this thread.
Webserver - You bring up a good point that I haven't thought of yet. At this time I just want to stop other contents from moving first. Then I will probably worry about others.
Charlietfl - sorry I didn't quite get your point. Are you saying to set a absolute position for the results div? This is not easy in my case because the results div is located in a table cell in middle of my page. I will try to think about a way to get a good absolute position though.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple ways you could approach this. One fairly easy, pure jquery option might be that you could start out with the $('#results') div hidden, append the html and then do a $('#results').slideDown() to make the transition more fluid.

So in other words, on getting your success response you would use

```
    $("#results").hide().html(response).slideDown();
```

Another thing you could possibly do would be sticking the results in an accordion/collapsable pane, and when it's filled trigger it to expand. Bootstrap has a great example of a collapsable pane: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the jquery slideDown option you suggest but still on sliding the response the other contents in the same page moves down.

Comment: not sure how to stick the results in a collapsable pane. I've looked at the link but still confused.